# How can create virtual machine from ovf in ESXI via vsphere client

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi

I had virtual machine exported in `OVF format`

Then i went to vsphere client and click on `Deploy OVF template`.

Then i choose the `ovf` from my local window machine and vmware starts uploading that to my datastore.

After few hours the system uploaded it to my data store and i can see the whole folder there with ovf and vmdk file.

but what should i do now.

How can i turn on that VM , there is no option there.

Look like vm is not created but files are in my data store how can i opne vmdk or ovf file which is in my data store

Comment: Can you review or upload the tasks done in status panel of vSphere Client?

Comment: i have tuned off the esxi and done many things since then , how can i get the previous tasks done

Answer (score 0):

Start creating New VM, name it and so on, and at step where you'll be asked about HDD just select "Use existing virtual disk" and navigate to your vmdk file location.

Comment: i did that abd but when i power on vm then i only see blank screen